# magento 2 bring key to first in customer address

Tags: magento2, customer-address

i have multidimension array as below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 45308,
    "firstname": "Sanku Pradeep"
  },
  {
    "id": 45309,
    "firstname": "Sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45310,
    "firstname": "sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45311,
    "firstname": "sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45312,
    "firstname": "abhi"
  }
]
```

i want to bring value with "id": 45310 to first as below.

```
[
  {
    "id": 45310,
    "firstname": "sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45308,
    "firstname": "Sanku Pradeep"
  },
  {
    "id": 45309,
    "firstname": "Sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45311,
    "firstname": "sanku"
  },
  {
    "id": 45312,
    "firstname": "abhi"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an answer which is my best guess,

This JSON you have posted has a behaviour which is inherited from JavaScript itself , first of all this is also considered as JSON object , and sorting or ordering of this object is not guaranteed.

Please see this link as another proof - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17229462/15590642

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229418/jsonobject-why-jsonobject-changing-the-order-of-attributes

As a solution you can always choose array to sort , but it is not possible here , so i have another approach which is to place your object key inside an array with value 0 , Please see an example where i build an array and push the elements which matches the id = 45310 in the first and convert that to JSON in PHP:

```
$jsonData = '[
          {
            "id": 45308,
            "firstname": "Sanku Pradeep"
          },
          {
            "id": 45309,
            "firstname": "Sanku"
          },
          {
            "id": 45310,
            "firstname": "sanku"
          },
          {
            "id": 45311,
            "firstname": "sanku"
          },
          {
            "id": 45312,
            "firstname": "abhi"
          }
        ]';
        $array = json_decode($jsonData, true);
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if ($value['id'] == "45310") {
                array_unshift($array, $value);
                break;
            }
        }
        $encodedJson = json_encode($array);
```

If this post helped you , please do give me a like as this helps me answer more.Thanks